# Enter key in JQueryUI datepicker submitting form

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

In JQueryUI's datepicker control, when I select a date and press enter, it "commits" the date and then I have to press enter again to submit the form. I would like to only have to press the enter key once and I'm not sure how to trigger that. I'm just not sure what to do in the enter key handler:

```
$(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'm/d/y' })
                     .bind("keydown", function (e) {
                       if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        //e.preventDefault();
                         //e.stopPropagation();
                         return true;
                        }
                      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.submit()` method to trigger the form submisson when the enter key is pressed:

```
$(el).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'm/d/y' 
}).on("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(el).closest('form').submit();          
    }
});
```

Also keep in mind that [according to jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), `.on()` is preferred over `.bind()`

Comment: I believe it is recommended to use `e.which` in jQuery to normalize functionality across browsers.

Comment: @kyle.stearns good point, thanks for the suggestion, I just updated the answer accordingly...